# Apigee Hybrid on Anthos GKE on prem

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, apigee, hybrid, google-anthos

I am working on **Apigee hybrid on Anthos GKE** on-prem setup, it's configured fully and I'm able to hit the APIs internally from the Admin machine, but I'm not able to access my APIs externally using Postman or from any browser.
I followed the below documentation to setup **Anthos GKE on-prem on six VM**

https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/bare-metal/1.7/try/gce-vms

By following I was simply able to use six VM as a single bare metal machine and create an anthos cluster on it and after followed the procedure in installing Apigee Hybrid on GKE-on-prem. and it worked with pods up but I was not able to access{hit} proxies from outside.

Thanks in advance if someone can provide any guidance.